# Background color is leaking into transparent color

Tags: html, web-deployment, css

I have managed to get the background-border transparency working perfectly but now I can't get the content to appear white by any means without it overlapping into the border image.

Here is what I have: http://gigadra.in/

What I need is this but where the text is (the content) I need the background to be white

I have tried:
-Setting background color (simply doesn't work as it sets the border color too.)
-using a repeating bg image (the transparency is still there but the image loads partly over the border)
-using span to make the text background white (this would work but it only covers around the exact area of the text leaving some of the background transparent and come of it white.

here is my code:

```
.blog {
border-width: 27px;
-moz-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
-webkit-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
-o-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
font-family: pokemon;
font-size: 9px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 20px;
border-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.3);

}
```

oddly enough it loads fine in Dreamweaver,

thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.blog {
    border-width: 27px;
    -moz-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
    -o-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
    /* border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;  Remove this line */
    font-family: pokemon;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px;
    border-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.3);
}
```

Its a dirty fix but it works

Comment: @user3286723 ha, Im still trying to answer that question myself. border-image is kinda buggy still. As I said, this is a quick and dirt fix, hence should be just temporary. so yea you should still find a way to structure your elements to get rid of this fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to put your post content into `div` tag with some `class` (`post-content` for example) and set background color for it.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qgg9j/ (check out the last post)

Comment: I get the idea I think, do you mean the content should be a separate div class with its own properties and I put this INSIDE the blog class? I just tried this but it messed up the entire page, in my head this should work though.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="blog">
    <div class="content_wrapper">
        <h1>text</h1>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content_wrapper{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Logically this works but everything in the website ended up inside the blog post for some reason.

Comment: @user3286723 it will work, i think there is something other problem which is ending up inside the blog.